# Return value from one Airflow DAG into another one

Tags: python, airflow

My DAG (let's call it DAG_A) starting another DAG (DAG_B) using the `trigger_dagrun` operator. DAG_B's tasks use XCOM and I would like to obtain XCOM value from one of the tasks of DAG_B's run (exactly the one I've started) upon completion.

Use of XCOM is not a hard requirement - basically any (reasonable) mechanism that Airflow itself provides would work. I can change DAG_B if needed.

Can't find any examples of such cases, so appreciate the help.

Plan B would be to make DAG_B save XCOM values into some persistent storage like DB or file together with some run id, and DAG_A will take it from there. But I would like to avoid such complications if some built-in mechanisms were available.

Comment: Airflow does not treat data as first-class citizen. XCOM is made in a way that supports metadata and not data exchange. I believe you would have to move your data to X (e.g. HDFS or S3) and forward metadata in XCOM of where the data is to the next task, that will pick that data from their.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* pull XCOM values from another dag, by passing in the `dag_id` to `xcom_pull()` (see the [`task_instance.xcom_pull()` function documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html#airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance.xcom_pull)). This works as long as you triggered the subdag *using the same execution date as your current DAG*. That's trivially achieved by templating the `execution_date` value:

```
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_dag_b",
    trigger_dag_id="DAG_B",
    execution_date="{{ execution_date }}",
    ...
)
```

Then, provided you used an `ExternalTaskSensor` sensor to wait for the specific task to have completed or used `wait_for_completion=True` in your `TriggerDagRunOperator()` task, you can later on pull the XCOM with `task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id="DAG_B", ...)` (add in task ids and/or the XCOM key you want to pull).

If you are not averse to coding a Python operator, you can also import the `XCom` model and just use its [`XCom.get_one()` method](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/xcom/index.html#airflow.models.xcom.BaseXCom.get_one) directly:

```
value = XCom.get_one(
    execution_date=ti.execution_date,
    key="target key",
    task_id="some.task.id",
    dag_id="DAG_B",
)
```

I've used similar techniques using a multi-dagrun trigger (to process a variable number of resources); this is trickier as in that case you can't re-use the execution date (each dagrun must have a unique (dag_id, execution_date) tuple).

In those cases I either used direct queries (joining the SQLAlchemy `XCom` model against the `DagRun` model using dagrun ids stored in an XCom by the trigger, instead of relying on the execution date matching), or avoided the whole issue by configuring the subdags *up front*. The latter is achieved by setting up the sub-dag with configuration telling it where to output results that the parent dag then picks up. The documentation doesn't appear to mention this properly, but the `conf` argument to `TriggerDagRun()` supports templating too, so you can generate a dictionary there as input to the sub-dag, tasks in the sub-dag then reference the configuration via `params`.

Comment: thanks for response! It seems to work for me. I was on vacation while bounty was active, so it expired. Anyone knows how I can give bounty to this answer?

Comment: @mrzodiak you can always start a _new_ bounty on your question, and select 'Reward existing answer' as the reason. You'll have to remember to actually award it still (the normal 2 day wait still applies, my answer won't be eligible for automatic awarding), and because it is a new bounty the minimum amount will be higher.